# TensorFlow: Applying a batch of batches of filters to a batch of batches of images

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, I have a tensor `x` with shape `[batch_of_batches_size,batch_of_images_size,image_height,image_width,nchannels]`. It represents a batch of batches of images. The first index of `x`, which I'll refer to as the "batch index", points to a specific batch, and the second index points to a specific image inside the batch. The three remaining indexes of `x` represent the image itself, which has dimensions `image_height`-by-`image_width` and `nchannels` channels.
I want to apply 2d convolutions to the images. The filters have height `filter_height` and width `filter_width`, and I want to use `'SAME'` padding and all strides equal to `1`. But for each batch index `i`, I want to apply a different set of filters. The filters tensor is named `w` and its shape is `[batch_of_batches_size,filter_height,filter_width,nchannels,nfilters]`. For each batch index `i`, what I want is to apply to the images `x[i,:,:,:,:]` the filter `w[i,:,:,:,:]` (similarly to how I would apply the function `conv2d`). I want all the results to be held in the tensor `y` with shape `[batch_of_batches_size,batch_of_images_size,image_height,image_width,nfilters]`, such that the result for this `i` would be in `y[i,:,:,:,:]`.

Mathematically, what I want is:

`y[i,j,k,l,m] = SUM_{a,b,u} x[i,j,a,b,u]*w[i,k+a,l+b,u,m]`

This is identical to `conv2d`, besides the first index `i`.

I'd like to know if there is a way of doing this, using built-in functions in TensorFlow. I know I can use a `for` loop over the first dimension (the batch index), and use `conv2d` on rehspaed slices of `x` and `filters` on each iteration. But is there a simpler, more efficient or more elegant way, that does not require slicing and indexing into tensors?

Some ideas that I had but didn't lead me to a solution were (1) to reshape\transpose `x` and `w`, use `conv2d` or `depthwise_conv2d`, and then reshape\transpose again. (2) to use `conv3d` on `x` and on a padded version of `w`.

Comment: conv3d seems like it should do what you want. you'd need to swap your first two dims around for it to work the way you described though i.e. the depth dimension would become your "batch index"

Comment: But the formula for a 3d convolution has summation over four indices (height,width,depth,channel) whereas I want a summation over three indices only.

Comment: You could probably get it to do what you want by setting the filter coefficients carefully but it would result in a lot of unnecessary calculations. Related github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
y = tf.map_fn(lambda u: tf.nn.conv2d(u[0],u[1],padding='SAME',strides=[1,1,1,1]),.elems=[x,w],dtype=tf.float32)
```

The `map_fn` function lets applying the `conv2d` operator to each first-dimension slice of `x` and `w`.

Comment: really helpful!